# Executing java jar file gives error when passing user.dir in command line?

Tags: java, executable-jar

When I run the following everything works fine:

```
# WORKS CORRECTLY
java -jar target/example.jar     

# GIVES AN ERROR
java -Duser.dir="/webapp" -jar target/example.jar
```

The error output is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.module.Main
```

I'm using Java 7.

My Manifest file is configured correctly in the jar file to contain the "Main-Class: com.module.Main"

I can't find an explanation for why this takes place.

Comment: `user.dir` is the current working directory, but setting it doesn't *change* the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure package name is correct on your class with main.
If your sourcesets are custom, IDE will amend your package with main.java. etc

Comment: I'm not using an IDE. I'm running from the command line. "java -jar target/example.jar" executes the jar file correctly, its only when I set "user.dir" that it gives the error.

Comment: I understand. But sometimes when you set your src dir to be the source and create a class then  main/java is actually a package and when creating a class in IDE it automatically puts that for you on the top, and you expect com.module.Main but it's actually main.java.com.module.Main - im trying to help here :) easy hint but worth checking I got caught for it once nearly for an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the user.dir changes your working directory, hence the location it tries to find the runnable class in. So by changing your working directory it can no longer find the class in the expected location. You can test this by setting your user.dir to "." and it will work.

Comment: Setting `user.dir` does *not* change your current working directory, and `.` is in effect the default.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html and yes that was my point. And if it doesn't change it then how do you explain the issue described?

Comment: Yes, I tried to set the user.dir to "." and its working now.

Comment: But the java.exe should complain that "Error: Unable to access jarfile". Instead, it is complaining that "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Answer (score -1):

user.dir is the current working directory for java. Here, you are asking it to run something from /webapp but your jar is at different location.

Comment: No, it's not complaining that the jar file is not found, it's complaining that the "Could not find or load main class com.module.Main"